# passing parameters through link_to method in ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, link-to

i have an index view that shows all available classes i want a link to "sign up for class" that redirects me to the "sign up" form and fill up some other values and when the sign up is created it saves the values that i filled up plus the foreign key of the class i just passed via the link to method

classes index:

```
<h1>Listof classes</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @classes.each do |class| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= class.id %></td>
        <td><%= class.name %></td>
        <td><%= class.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'sign up!', new_sign_up_path(:class_id => class.id), method: :post %></td> 
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

sign_up controller:

```
class SignUpsCOntroller < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_sign_ups, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /sign_ups/new
  def new
    @sign_up = SignUp.new
  end

    def set_sign_ups
      @sign_up = SignUp.find(params[:id])
    end

    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:sign_up).permit(:date, :status, :type, :class_id)
    end
end
```

and my sign ups form:

```
<%= form_for(@sign_up) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :status %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :type %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :class_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

when i save it it doesn't save the the class_id... i've tried parsing it to integer i've tried it without the hidden field but it allways passes it as blank en saving... any ideas?

Comment: Name your variable something other than `class` - that is a reserved word in Ruby.

Comment: Seconded. If you start naming variables `class` and `type` you are going to enter a world of pain.

Comment: they're actually called different since my code is in spanish i change it when i post something

Comment: Do you know what's in the hash when it enters your controller? To see exactly which params and the associated values are coming from your form you could add a debug alert in your controller action to show you the hash. The code is flash[:info] = "Hash: #{params}" I've found this very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just passing in `params[:class_id]` with your extra parameter on the `link_to`. Your form however is for an object with a `class_id` attribute so it is expecting your `@sign_up` object to have a `class_id` attribute.

Basically for your `new` action you'll need to set up `@sign_up` with the `class_id` for it from the parameters:

```
def new
  @sign_up = SignUp.new
  @sign_up.class_id = params[:class_id] if params.has_key?(:class_id)
end
```

This will set the `class_id` to the parameter passed in from the `link_to` url.

Then your form should work okay because the `f.hidden_field` will look at the current value of `class_id` on `@sign_up` and set that as the value of the input. It doesn't matter that you haven't saved it at this point - the `form_for` will use the unsaved state to populate the inputs.

Comment: I'm not even sure now where `@daw_inscripcion` comes from. Should this form actually be for `@sign_up`?

Comment: yes yes sorry it's just that my code is in spanish i change it when i post something sorry

Comment: De nada (you're not going to get much more spanish than that out of me I'm afraid!)

Comment: jajaja it's a good start though xD.... and now that i edited the question do you see a solution?

Comment: could you explain why has_key? what does it do? how will it solve it? hehe just curious

Comment: The `has_key?` is just an extra check to make sure that the parameters do actually have a `class_id` value in them before setting it on `@sign_up`. You might not need it but if `class_id` already had a default value, say, then it would avoid overwriting it with `nil` if there was nothing in the parameters.

Comment: and how would i pass another parameter called profile_id? i want it to be the current_user.id.... i added another hidden field and passed it as `<%= f.hidden_field :daw_profile_id, :value => current_user.id %>` value and it doesn't work is there a way to do iti like class_id, through the new action in the controller?

Comment: If it is always going to be the `current_user.id` then you don't need to pass it around. You can just set it when you need to in the controller.

Comment: Done, hehe yeah i figured it out thanks man appreciate the help